# Java Buffer mark and reset in a for loop

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I've seen production code that mark and rest a buffer position initialized in a for loop every time. Is it necessary?

```
 */
public static void writeToBuffer(final List<ByteBuffer> attachments, final ByteBuffer buffer) {
    for (ByteBuffer buf : attachments) {
        buf.mark();
        // copy content of buf to buffer
        buf.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends. What is `attachments` and how is it used after the `for` loop finishes?

Comment: after the for loop finishes, is the buf even available outside of the `for` loop. It is the end of the function in this case.

Comment: I updated the code samples to include the function

Comment: You've updated the code to show the method signature, but you're still not saying what happens to `attachments` after the method returns. Does the caller re-read the buffers held in the `attachments` list?

Comment: I believe the reason to `mark` and `reset` in each `loop` is that we can copy the content from each member of `attachments` to position 0 of `buf` each time so we can avoid allocating more space than necessary. If we don't `reset`, in next iteration, additional content will be copied to the end of current position of `buf`. Does my explanation make sense?

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding you, or you're getting confused. `buf` is a reference variable that refers to the *same* object as an element of the list, `attachments`. I don't see any copying going on here. All you're doing by doing `buf.mark` and `buf.reset` is resetting the mark of each element of `attachments`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes that is necessary, if you want to be able to go back to the buffers position before you started reading them in the loop later in your code.

**Example:**

the position before starting to read the buffer, this is where the mark is set

--x-------------

// After reading the buffer the position is (possibly) at the end

----------------X

// Call to reset will move back to the marked position so we can read the bytes again.

--x-------------

From the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html):

> A buffer's mark is the index to which its position will be reset when the reset method is invoked. The mark is not always defined, but when it is defined it is never negative and is never greater than the position. If the mark is defined then it is discarded when the position or the limit is adjusted to a value smaller than the mark. If the mark is not defined then invoking the reset method causes an InvalidMarkException to be thrown.

Comment: But the OP shows that the `reset()` happens at the end of the `for` block, with no more statements after it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I see, my answer is a little unclear, I will clarify it. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: the scope of `buf` is inside the `for` loop, correct? Every `for` loop will create a new `buf` so I am still confused on why it is necessary to `mark` and `reset`

Comment: @niepan "every loop will create a new `buf`" - yes, but that's a new *reference* to an *existing* ByteBuffer object. After the loop, that ByteBuffer object won't go away. It will still be accessible as an element of the `attachments` list.